# Making HTML buttons from an array of names, and inserting them into the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, button

I can't figure out how to make these into buttons using the array:

```
var widgetButtons = ["Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Pan", "Search"]
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is my code I am attempting to use

```
   <body>
   <div id="demo"></div>
   <script>
        var widgetButtons = ["Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Pan", 
        "Search"];
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do it, using `forEach()`.

IDs cannot contain spaces, so we remove the space from the item's name/text before setting the id.

```js
const widgetButtons = ["Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Pan", "Search"]
const demo = document.getElementById('demo');

widgetButtons.forEach( (item, idx) => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.id = item.replace(' ', '');
  btn.innerText = item;
  demo.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="demo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML: `<div id="new">`

In your JS / script:

```
var widgetButtons = ["Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Pan",
      "Search"];
    var element = document.getElementById("new");

    for (const widgetButtonsKey of widgetButtons) {
      var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      x.innerText = widgetButtonsKey
      console.log(x);
      element.appendChild(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

```js
var widgetButtons = ["Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Pan", "Search"];
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = widgetButtons.map(text=>{
  return `<button>${text}</button>`;
}).join(' ');
```

```html
<div id=demo></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const demo = document.getElementById("demo");

    var widgetButtons = ["Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Pan", 
    "Search"];

    //Loop through the array
    for (let index = 0; index < widgetButtons.length; index++) 
    {
        //Create button element using create element
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        //This adds button value (title of the button)
        button.innerHTML = widgetButtons[index];
        //Add style to increase margin
        button.style.margin = "10px";
        //Append the buttons created to the body
        demo.appendChild(button);
     }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).